# getting a list of folders/files in current directory

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best way to display the folders/files name on the html page of it's home directory. This html files is on client machine which only requires to access locally and from it's own home directory.
As i tried using `var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");` but it's only accessible in `IE` and i can not access in `firefox/chrome`.

Please let me know if we can access the file/folders list which i want to display on the html page.

Comment: actually js cannot access local file system

Comment: `<a href="file://C:/FolderName">Folder</a>`?

Comment: @ArunKillu [this is not true.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript/372333#372333)

Comment: @sytycs in web context browser restrict the js.

Comment: @Teemu unsafe js attempt

Comment: @ArunKillu How is that? It's a regular HTML link, no JS involved. Works fine in FF and IE. I've not other browsers available to test when still at work...

Comment: call using some domain name,server

Comment: @ArunKillu Why? "`This html files is on client machine which only requires to access locally and from it's own home directory`". Quoted from OP's comment. At least I understood this to mean a standalone desktop app, I might be wrong...

Comment: ok ...so i wish u a Happy New Year...

Comment: @Teemu yes,you got it right, but it doesn't suit to my requirement.

Comment: @user1010399 So, did you follow sytycs' link, there seems to be many interesting links on that page :-).

Comment: @user1010399 Yep, [this is not true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript/372333#372333) is a link ; ), on that SO page there's something useful for you (I guess), and more behind some links at that page...

Answer (score -1):

I will repeat @Arum Killu words "actually js cannot access local file system" from inside a browser.
You are going on in a dead end direction IMHO. If you want a local off-line stand alone system you can try a local http server or use local storage. Optionally you can put the pages locally and make an index page or frame that show the structure with links.